# limit swarm from creating more than X number of containers per node

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

is there any to limit swarm from creating for example 20 number of containers per worker. so, one worker wouldn't have more than 20 containers for better QoS (Quality of service), this'll also prevent overcommitting host's resources?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

> This is now implemented and it will be released as part of Docker
> 19.03.
>
> You can see how it works with stack on docker/cli#1410 and with
> without stack (docker service ...) on docker/cli#1612

[Source](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26259)

---

**Actually no.**

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26259) who is talking about it.

Comment: Update: looks like this has been implemented and should be available as `max-replicas-per-node` when Docker CE 19.03 is released.

Comment: If you use Docker Swarm, you can use max_replicas_per_node: 20 within the "placement" section of your compose file.

Answer (score 7):

For docker-ce 19.03+, you can simply create/update your service with the `--replicas-max-per-node` option:

```
# create service with replicas-max-per-node=10
docker service create --replicas=100 --replicas-max-per-node=10 --name your_service_name your_image_name

# update service with replicas-max-per-node=20
docker service update --replicas-max-per-node=20 your_service_name
```

[read more](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1612)

### UPDATE (2020-04-10)

```
- Add 3.8 compose version
    Limit service scale to the size specified by the field deploy.placement.max_replicas_per_node
```

[read more](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.5)

Comment: This is reasonable; however, for production environments, we prefer to use a docker-compose to deploy the system in to the swarm. Apparently this is not implemented! (AFAIK there is no plan to do it yet)

Comment: @S.SaeidHosseini I am also looking for a way to use replicas max per node in the docker-compose setup.

Comment: @S.SaeidHosseini Have you got a solution to get this done via docker-compose..? Could you please share solution.Thanks

Comment: @LeoPrince `docker stack deploy -c xxx.yml xxx` See: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/10652 and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/

Answer (score 4):

You can't exactly say "Limit to 20 containers" per node.  If memory is your issue you can look into using limits and reservation in your stack files. This will tell the scheduler to not schedule containers on the node if there isn't enough memory.   There are also CPU reservation/limits you can set but that doesn't seem to influence the schedules.

This link on compose is helpful in learning about limits and reservation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources

```
  my-java-service:
    image: yourcompany.com/my-java-service:1.1.0
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.env.lifecyle==prod
      replicas: 40
      resources:
        reservations:
          memory: 5120M
      update_config:
        delay: 1m
        parallelism: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
```